# sitecore XP to XM : Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found

Tags: solr, xm-cloud

I am deploying my XP solution to XM.

I disabled xdb, analytics from project.

created custom indexes in solr

and then deployed the whole solution to sc102xmcm.dev.local.

it is giving following error:

```
[ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters: ]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +574
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +842
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +309
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +734
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.get_CsConfig() +16
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.GeAllIndexes() +11
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.DefaultSolrStartUp..ctor(BaseSearchIndexes indexes) +59
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs args) +72
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +898
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters: ]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724
```

And in the logs, I am getting following error:

```
22424 18:37:11 ERROR Error loading hook: <hook type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
Message: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters: 
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Events.Hooks.HookManager.LoadAll()
```

Anybody faced similar issue or have any insights to resolve it.

Comment: Search topic works differently in xmCloud.
You can not create custom solr index, even if you do, when you want to deploy it to xmCloud environment, you will not be able to create any custom index, because you will not have access to the deployed Solr instance in Kubernetes.

For implementing the Search, you need to use external search provider, like Sitecore Search for crawling.
If you want to push the data to index and not using the crawling, which I do not recommend, you may want to use the webhooks, and publish end events.